# Unsigned long long wrong given value after add

Tags: c++, addition, unsigned-long-long-int, long-long

I have two strings to add. Strings is HEX values. I convert strings to long long, add and after I back to string. But this operation no working good.

Code:

```
unsigned long long FirstNum = std::strtoull(FirstString.c_str(), NULL, 16);
unsigned long long SecondNum = std::strtoull(SecondString.c_str(), NULL, 16);
unsigned long long Num = FirstNum + SecondNum;
std::cout << "  " << FirstNum << "\n+ " << SecondNum << "\n= " << Num << "\n\n";
```

I received

```
  13285923899203179534
+ 8063907133566997305
= 2903086959060625223
```

Anyone can explain me this magic? How can I fix it?

Back to hex value by

```
std::stringstream Stream;
Stream << std::hex << Num;
return Stream.str();
```

Comment: You have a simple case of overflow here. Those numvers do not fit 64bit integers.

Comment: @SergeyA okay. I think that is my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All unsigned arithmetic in C (and C++) occurs modulo 2<sup>k</sup> for some k.  In your case, you are getting the result modulo 2<sup>64</sup>, implying that unsigned long long is 64 bits on your platform.

If you want to do arithmetic with integers larger than the largest supported type on your platform, you'll need to use a multiprecision library such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think that is my mistake. Thank you :)